# Prove the two following properties are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f\colon[a,b]\mapsto[0,+\infty)$ denote a bounded function.

$(1)$For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$$

$(2)$For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)\leq9\epsilon$$

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Assume it's true for $\epsilon$ then it's true for $\epsilon \cdot 9$. And otherwise

Comment: @Rigel:  that question looks the same, but I don't see any answer there

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes they are both mine. I reuploaded it with a thank you as one commenter seemed a bit sarcastic at my post.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, let $S$ be a set and $F\colon S\to\Bbb R$ a function. Then the following are equivalent:

1. For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $s\in S$ with $F(s)<\epsilon$
2. For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $s\in S$ with $F(s)<9\epsilon$